# MySQL converting to TINYINT

Tags: mysql, sql, tinyint

Under what circumstances will MySQL convert types to TINYINT? I know that a BOOL or BOOLEAN type in mysql DDL will automatically be converted to TINYINT(1) for for true or false. I am analyzing a database which has a type of varchar(16) on a field in one table, and tinyint(4) on the same field on another table? E.g t1.name varchar(15) and t2.name tinyint(4) where t1.name=t2.name.

Comment: Very bad choice for a `join` condition.  The types should be the same.

Comment: But could it be that they might be a third unkown table that perhaps joins the table tables indirectly by directly joining to t2.name e.g create table t3(id...PK, ws_connect tinyint(4), name varchar(16));?

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on implicit type conversion, do your datatype analysis manually:

First lets see what MySQL thinks as the best col-type for your data. Run a

```
 SELECT * FROM table PROCEDURE Analyse()
```

Analyse your data further by saying

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE varcharCol NOT REGEXP '^[0-9].*$'
```

To get all non-numeric values in varcharCol. If there are non you finally have to check value-ranges of different MySQL-types [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html).

Then you are ready to convert your varcharCol e.g. to TINYINT.